# pass a function as a parameter to be executed later

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to pass this function:

```
const upgradeAction = () => (
  (dispatch) => {
    closeModal('modal')
    dispatch(showUserInfo())
  }
)
```

as a parameter here:

```
export const checkComplete = () => (
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(openModal('modalname', {
      buttonAction: upgradeAction,
    }))
  }
)
```

checkComplete is called on a button click. However now when the button is clicked nothing works. I tried to use return on upgradeAction but nothing works and checkComplete does nothing. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: How do you attach `checkComplete` to the click listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a redux middleware (probably [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)) to handle function actions. When a function is dispatch, the middleware detects the function, and calls it with `dispatch` and `setState`.

When the modal executes the `buttonAction` it doesn't dispatch it. You need to supply the `dispatch` manually, and when the button will call the action, it will be dispatched.

```js
const upgradeAction = (dispatch) => () => {
  closeModal('modal')
  dispatch(showUserInfo())
};

export const checkComplete = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(openModal('modalname', {
    buttonAction: upgradeAction(dispatch),
  }))
}
```

Comment: you're genius that was it, thanks for the explanation I am using redux-thunk that was the problem.